# os.environ doesn't show some environment variables

Tags: python, operating-system

I have set one variable called ANDROID_HOME as "/home/test/android-sdk", but when I do

```
env_var = os.environ
pprint.pprint(dict(env_var), width = 1)
```

The result doesn't show some of the environment variables and my ANDROID_HOME variable as well.

(The above code is to show all the mappings in the os.environ)

Comment: You need to restart your Python Shell after setting the environment variables.

Comment: Still not fetching

Comment: How did you solve this issue?